# How to split multiple in javascript string

Tags: javascript, string, split

Hi I am new at learning JavaScript.

Here is my string "Hello (mon) super (Henry)"
there is another string "Hello (wed) class (Mario)"

I wish to not have (mon) and (wed), and things beyond it.

I tried

```
let dummyString = 'Hello (wed) class';
dummyString = dummyString.split('(mon)')[0];
dummyString = dummyString.split('(wed)')[0];
console.log(dummyString);
```

this works perfect but when I use below code

```
let dummyString = 'Hello (wed) class';
dummyString = dummyString.split('(mon),(wed)')[0];
console.log(dummyString);
```

it doesn't work

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ - Because that's just not how it works. You would have to use a regular expression as argument for `.split()` -> [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: You can split by regex.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant for the question. `jquery` and `console` are not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A regex replacement is probably the most straightforward approach here:

```js
var inputs = ["Hello (mon) super", "Hello (wed) class"];
inputs = inputs.map(x => x.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/, " ").trim());
console.log(inputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split with `(` and `)` with irrespective of the string it contains in between.

```js
let dummyString = 'Hello (wed) class';

console.log(dummyString.split(' (')[0], dummyString.split(') ')[1])
```

Comment: Extremely sorry other few string also contains other (Cary), (Felon) etc. even they will get removed I guess. I have days of week mentioned which I wish to remove from string.